# Excel Truncates values with spaces between the text

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have a strange situation with Excel 2010 VBA.  I am using ADODB recordset to get data from Teradata database and assign the value to Excel cells. One of the values which has spaces between the whole text is getting truncated. Not sure why this is happening.

When I point the cursor to the recordset value it doesn't show the entire value, but when I do `?rs.fields(0)` in the immediate window, it shows me the entire text. Below is the text I am expecting to return and which is supposed to be assign to the Excel cell:

```
POSO200 PRICING OPT ERR                 C7
```

However, it truncates at

```
POSO200 PRICING OPT ERR
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! How are you "[pointing] the cursor to the recordset value"? Showing some of your code would be helpful for troubleshooting this.

Comment: If you can post a screenshot or two, that might help.